# ANR on Google's billing library

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

Anyone have any idea why this ANR might be happening? I thought upgrading from the old IABHelper to the new billing library would solve it but it didn't. I submitted a bug on the billing library sample on github but haven't heard anything.

This is happening on Android 7 and 8. I have never had it happen to me, I only see it on the Play Store console.

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x73ad8e30 self=0x7d456c7a00
  | sysTid=21462 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7d4a0fd9b0
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2078 stm=1145 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7ff79b5000-0x7ff79b7000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000001de2c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 00000000000e1a5c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+152)
  #02  pc 00000000004e12c4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL12GoToRunnableEPNS_6ThreadE+440)
  #03  pc 00000000004e10c4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12JniMethodEndEjPNS_6ThreadE+28)
  #04  pc 0000000000987c3c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_BinderProxy_transactNative__ILandroid_os_Parcel_2Landroid_os_Parcel_2I+220)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native method)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:766)
  at com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.isBillingSupported (IInAppBillingService.java:320)
  at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl$BillingServiceConnection.onServiceConnected (BillingClientImpl.java:839)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected (LoadedApk.java:1713)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run (LoadedApk.java:1742)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6703)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:769)
```